# How to hide accordion on click

Tags: jquery, html

Ey, I found some code that would make my open accordion close when I select another accordion. But it just bugs hard(hiding the accordions I click OR with other code it just slides the accordions together.). And when the page opens I want the first accordion to be opened automatically so I did that with "checked" if there is a better way to do this I'm open for some suggestions. :D

**HTML:**

```
<div class="accordion-bral">

 <div>  <!-- accordion item 1 -- start -->
   <input class="ac-input" id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" checked/>
   <label class="ac-label" for="ac-1">HTML and CSS only<i></i></label>
   <div class="article ac-content">
   </div>
 </div>
 <!-- accordion item 1 -- end -->

 <div> <!-- accordion item 2 -- start -->
   <input class="ac-input" id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
   <label class="ac-label" for="ac-2">responsive accordion<i></i></label>
   <div class="article ac-content">
   </div>
 </div>
 <!-- accordion item 2 -- end -->

 <div>  <!-- accordion item 3 -- start -->
   <input class="ac-input" id="ac-3" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
   <label class="ac-label" for="ac-3">Divs to divide your things up<i></i></label>
   <div class="article ac-content">

   </div>
 </div>
 <!-- accordion item 3 -- end -->

 <div>  <!-- accordion item 4 -- start -->
   <input class="ac-input" id="ac-4" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
   <label class="ac-label" for="ac-4">Forms are cool<i></i></label>
   <div class="article ac-content">
   </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.accordion-bral').find('.ac-input').click(function(){

    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

    //Hide the other panels
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

  });
});
```

Hope someone knows what is wrong with the code that makes it bug.

Comment: "it just bugs hard" isn't a particularly meaningful description of the problem.  What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very confused... are you by any meaning trying to create something like that:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.accordion').accordion();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

h1:not(.ui-state-active) {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

div {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.accordion {
  background-color: black;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 50px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.accordion>div,
.accordion>h1 {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="accordion">
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <div>
    <p>
      This is text to title 1 This is text to title 1 This is text to title 1 This is text to title 1 This is text to title 1 This is text to title 1 This is text to title 1
    </p>
  </div>
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <div>
    <p>
      This is text to title 2 This is text to title 2 This is text to title 2 This is text to title 2 This is text to title 2 This is text to title 2 This is text to title 2 This is text to title 2
    </p>
  </div>
  <h1>Title 3</h1>
  <div>
    <p>
      This is text to title 3 This is text to title 3 This is text to title 3 This is text to title 3 This is text to title 3 This is text to title 3 This is text to title 3 This is text to title 3
    </p>
  </div>
  <h1>Title 4</h1>
  <div>
    <p>
      This is text to title 4 This is text to title 4 This is text to title 4 This is text to title 4 This is text to title 4 This is text to title 4
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If yes, that's great :D My snippet is not optimized at all though (the rounded corners when you switch items). For more detailed and pretty information take a look at the [reference](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

**NOTE:** This does require you to include [JQueryUi](https://jqueryui.com/).